How are frequency drops and surges handled in grids without spinning generators?
In most electric grids around the world frequencies of 50 or 60Hz are used. As I understand it the grids consumers run in parallel and grid resistance drops when another consumer is added. If voltage is supposed to stay the same the current has to increase to satisfy Ohm's law.
I further understand that energy is current times voltage and therefore a generator needs to produce more energy if a consumer taps into the grid. I don't understand the electromagnetic concept behind it but needing to produce more energy while holding a steady speed to hold frequency is to a generator like someone is pushing against it's effort to spin.
Therefore, if you don't pump more pressurized steam into your generators turbine it will slow down, drop frequency and voltage and finally blackout the grid.
As I understand it frequency and voltage drop synchronously. Probably there is some law explaining why.
To keep voltage and current steadily around optimal levels (50Hz and 230V in low voltage parts of the system [Europe]) there are grid services called frequency response (part of ancillary services).
Since solar rectifiers and batteries have no spinning parts, does it work for them like this?
They usually run at full capacity and if there was no reserve within the grid as soon as an additional consumer taps into the grid the frequency and voltage would drop and the grid would black out. And to avoid this you have to run solar and battery sources below max capacity to maintain reserves to ramp up in case of demand surges. This could act and can be sold as frequency response.
Is this correct?

Basically a PLL tied to an inverter running of batteries. This concept is called "synthetic inertia" because you do away the need for actually spinning generators. It's one of the selling points you find on contemporary battery array installers. The advantage over spinning generators is that the batteries contain much more energy, so they double as primary frequency response too.


As I understand it frequency and voltage drop synchronously. Probably there is some law explaining why.

You explained it just in the paragraph above this paragraph:
The collected users of electric power draw more current, which increases the load on the generator, which increases the generator's mechanical load on the spinning turbine, which slows down the turbine.
The frequency of electricity that such an AC generator produces is directly defined by the speed at which it rotates.
For grids with mixed types of generation, the grid frequency is still used as a primary means of communicating demand/supply relationship: if the frequency is below the nominal (say) 50 Hz, you, as a power plant operator, need to increase your power output, if it's above, you need to reduce it.

They usually run at full capacity

no, they run grid-synchronously and produce a pseudo-sinusoidal signal at the nominal voltage that they should. That means they run below capacity, some or most of the time!
The reason why they might be running more or less often below or above capacity than other types of power plants will be defined by commercial factors; there's different kind of contracts for delivery of energy between grid operators and power producers, such as cases where the grid buys a fixed amount of power for a defined time (e.g., an hour), and the power will be paid for exactly that, whether they deliver it or overly high grid frequency "forces" them to reduce the amount the power they feed into the grid. Other contracts are more of the "you can sell us up to so and so many MW in 15 minute packages, depending on how much our grid needs it, as you will notice by the grid frequency". As you can imagine, the markets for these different kinds of electricity productions yield to different prices per MWh, and operators will be required to shut down the fast-acting and high-priced plants first, then the cheaper once, and only finally the ones from whom they buy a fixed package.
These markets often use interesting variants of auctions, and hence are a playground for economic game theorists of all makes. I cannot find an English wikipedia article equivalent to the German wikipedia Kraftwerkseinsatzoptimierung (Power Plant Utilization Optimization), but it's a start.

and if there was no reserve within the grid as soon as an additional consumer taps into the grid the frequency and voltage would drop and the grid would black out.

Not that fast; voltage drops do happen; you'll notice that there's a few volts in tolerance for grid voltages.
But yes, one can overload the electricity distribution network, at which point things will fail. For example, in an overload situation, an electricity provider might have to drop a large industrial consumer (say, a copper refinery) until the grid stabilizes, or in worse cases, cut off whole regions.
That happens very rarely in highly industrialized nations, North America excluded, and is usually result of a systemic failure that exacerbates supply problems by combining them with grid problems and things like administrative failures.

This could act and can be sold as frequency response.

"frequency response" means something different in electrical engineering, but what you mean is

The grid inverters of solar power plants that run below their maximum supply capacity are capably of rapidly reacting to changing demand. Is there economic value to that which can be sold?

And the answer is: kind of.
The ability to react to load changes quickly is important; but so is predictability of availability. Because, due to the statistical nature of unpredictable consumers (copper refineries can just tell the network operators that they'll start drawing 200 MW starting Monday 5am, what's unpredictable are the many smaller consumers), unexpected demand changes never happen abruptly (exception: catastrophic failures, e.g. the main transport lines into an industrial region tumble), especially not unexpected abrupt demand increases. So, you typically have enough time between noticing that your turbines turn slower than nominal, hence your grid frequency drops below the nominal frequency, and before it gets critical.
So, the quick demand response is often carried by forms of power plants where you can increase power production by a significant percentage within minutes – gas turbines, pumped-storage hydroelectric plants, and certainly, if available (because good weather during daytime) also solar plants.
So, it's desirable to have enough such plants online at any time of the day. In fact, you'll find that most electricity authorities will have special regulations that forces the network operators to buy at least a certain amount of rapidly dispatchable capacity; they will also force them to have enough back-up power plants that can spin up fast enough, e.g. when the weather gets bad (and that also doesn't happen nation-wide instantly, so you get a few minutes before the stormfront has covered a significant amount of solar sites).
Thus, the commercially valuable asset there is

the reliability with which you can rapidly dispatch energy
the "rapidness" of that.

Solar wins on 2., but loses on 1., because the amount of capacity reserved for rapid dispatch needs to be "booked" beforehand, and you can't really predict the weather.
Coming back to your other question, how that is technologically solved: the inverters of solar power plants in composite grids will probably just stay synchronous to the below-nominal grid frequency and increase their output voltage to effect an increased power flow into the grid. This would allow the "classical" turbine-based plants to operate at reduced mechanical load, thus bringing their spinning back to nominal rates.
In purely solar microgrids with no such primary means of frequency regulation, the question would be why the frequency dropped in the first place – the spinning-slower mechanism doesn't exist there.
